# Basic Probability Question Coins

Tags: probability

You have a box with 5 coins.

1 of the coins is weighted so that it comes up heads with probability 0.2. (Category 1)

2 is weighted so that they comes up heads with probability 0.3. (Category 2)

2 are weighted so that they come up heads with probability 0.9. (Category 3)

A. What is the probability of heads, if you pick a coin at random and flip it?

B. Suppose that you pick three coins at random from the box and you flip each of them 10 times.
What is the expected total number of heads? Justify your answer. (Hint: Use random variables.
This is easy, once you have done part (A). If you start enumerating the possible combinations of
categories, you are on the wrong track.)

For A, my answer is:

$0.2\times0.2+2\times0.2\times0.3 + 2\times0.2\times0.9 = 0.52$

What's the best way to approach B? I don't really follow the hint. My intuition was to do the combinatorics route...

Comment: Part (a) is good.  For part (b), you have $H_{tot} = H_1 + H_2 + H_3$ and you take expectations of that equation.  Each $H_i$ is simply a random variable associated with taking a random coin and flipping it 10 times. The $H_i$ values are not independent, but that does not matter.

Comment: Linearity of Expectation holds _even if the random variables are dependent_.  Kinda amazing until you get used to it.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Michael. Just to be sure I understand correctly, each $H_i$ would be $10\times0.52$, so the answer to B) would be $10\times0.52\times3$ right?